# What design pattern is better?

Tags: design-patterns

When writing a function with 2 objects as an arguments, like a compare function or vectors sum, what design pattern is better?

1) Writing the function inside the objects class, and get only the second object.

2) Writing an outside class with a static function, that will get both objects.

Why and when?

Comment: @Dervall I don't think it is important. Any high level OOP language.

Comment: Your question is too vague. We need to know what this function will do, what exactly does it return.

Comment: @Vadiklk It does matter what language is being concerned, as design patterns are often language specific: http://norvig.com/design-patterns/

Comment: @piokuc But is it true for that specific case?

Comment: @Jason Evans for example 2 objects and a compare function that returns a value.

Comment: @Vadikkl I think the question is a bit too vague to answer 1 or 2 with confidence, at least to me, it would be easier if it was known what this function is supposed to do, but for example in C++, which is a language with function overloading, I would say the second option is normally more powerful and flexible. Also, the function doesn't have to be a static function in a class, but just a free function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java you have [`Comparable.compareTo(o1)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) that is executed on behalf of one object and takes second object as an argument:

```
apple.compareTo(orange);
```

There is also [`Comparator.compare(o1,o2)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29) abstraction:

```
comparator.compare(apple, orange);
```

None of them are deprecated and none of them are considered better.  They are both used in different scenarios:

- if there is a fixed, natural "order" of fruit, put it inside `Fruit` class
- if there are multiple different ways you can compare fruit by (size, weight, color, taste), have several comparators and use whichever you need at a time.

You can even combine them: you default ordering (encoded inside `Fruit`) as long as the default order suits you. If one day you need a different order, choose specific comparator.

I believe this scales to other similar situations and languages.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, coming from the .NET background: **If any of the objects might be null, use a static method.**

If the first (left object) is bound to be non-null, and you'd like to make it possible for inheriting classes to provide their own implementations of the equality method, use an instance method.